# Can my time in the UK be defined as transit?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, canadian-citizens

On the 29th of January I landed in the UK.

On the morning of the 31st of January, I left the UK to Norway.

Was my time in the UK short enough to be defined as transit? I was only there to switch airports and catch a flight to Oslo. I'm asking as I am filling out a working visa application and I want to define this correctly.

Should I list this as 2 or 3 days?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you have a UK Visitor in Transit Visa?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I didn't need a visa as I'm from Canada.

Comment: Easy part of the question: 3 days--every day counts. If you were admitted (I assume you couldn't stay airside), how many days were you given? If it was the usual 6 mo or even 30 days, it wasn't transit.

Comment: @mkennedy I was given the usual 6 months. But this was after I had already been in the UK for a while earlier. I made it clear to the immigration officer I was only staying for three days. As she was wondering why I was back so soon. I told her I was only there to go from Gatwick to Heathrow and catch a flight to Oslo.

Comment: When I was admitted while in transit between two different airports, I received a 48 hour admission stamp. Admittedly my flights were only 20 hours apart.

Comment: This defines ‘transit’ as leaving the U.K. within 48 hours of arrival https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/674190/transit-guidance-v2.0ext.pdf

Comment: I find it quite strange that you waited over two days to get a flight from London to Oslo. There are multiple daily flights between these two cities. And it doesn't take _that_ long to get from Gatwick to Heathrow...most of the time! Are you sure you did nothing else while in London? Looked at Buckingham Palace? Did some high street shopping? Were you just holed up in your hotel room the whole time? I expect you should not try to claim this was a transit, but a short stopover visit.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Stansted-Oslo tomorrow (4th Nov) €252, two days later €15. I'd definitely wait two days if I were not in a hurry. Perhaps doing nothing special, just getting over jet lag.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Berendi's reason was why I stayed an extra day, I saved a lot of money by doing so.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I'd do the same if the hotel didn't cost more than the difference in airfares (and if I weren't under a time constraint).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you were admitted as a visitor, since you were given six months.  It would still be reasonable to describe the purpose of your visit as "transit," however, since that was in fact the purpose of your visit.

Answer (score 9):

UK specifically **limits transit to 48 hours**

[Visitor in Transit visa](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa)

> You might need a Visitor in Transit visa if you’re from outside the
>   European Economic Area (EEA) and Switzerland and you’ll:
>
> - be changing flights in the UK on your way to another country
> - go through immigration control, for example to check in your luggage    for a connecting flight
> - leave the UK **within 48 hours**
> - not work or study while in the UK

I would use that criteria. In your case I would say it is 3 days and hence not transit however either way no big deal.

Comment: Leaving on the morning of the 31st after arriving on the 29th might indeed have been a visit of shorter than 48 hours.  If the arrival was after noon on the 29th, it was certainly shorter than 48 hours.

Answer (score 3):

It's a pretty grey area, but if your only purpose for being there was to get on another plane, and you couldn't have reasonably got on an earlier plane, then yes your reason for being there was transit. If they are asking your reason for then 'transit' would be a good answer. If they are asking what visa you had then there ought to be a box for 'didn't need a visa'. Frankly since you don't need a visa for the UK your answer is going to make no significant difference.